# std::terminate undefined in Cocoa App

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have a Cocoa app that compiles and links fine. I've since broken out some of the code into a static library and then have gone back and tried to link that libMyLib.a library to my original program.

I now get a linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
```

referencing one of the source modules that use to live in my main project, but now lives in the library.

I've tried to go back and match up each compiler and linker setting to see which one is different, but I just can't seem to nail it down. My hunch is that I'm linking with a C STD and need a C++ STD, but everything is using the C99 compiler with standard libs.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: linking in libc++.dylib fixed the issue

Comment: WebDrive, and @Scicare, please add an answer and award the points and bounty respectively.

Answer (score 41):

linking in libc++.dylib fixed the issue

Comment: how do you link that? :)

Comment: add libc++.dylib to the list of libraries in the Linker section of the build options

Comment: For Xcode 7 and more recent version, the lib's name is libc++.tbd instead of libc++.dylib

Comment: Thanks :) It Works like a charm :)