# std::terminate() linker error on a small clang project

Tags: c++, compilation, clang, llvm, ld

I'm getting the following error on a project that links with clang (verbose output):

```
clang++ `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs --system-libs` -lc++ -fno-rtti -o gen -lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic -I /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include src/main.cpp -v
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 253.9 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2 -D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -I /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include -I /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/samvv/Projects/ffi-enhanced/xfi-gen -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 142 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fno-rtti -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.10.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/9g/8c11l8090p524v5r7873yghc0000gn/T/main-918e82.o -x c++ src/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 7.0.2 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o gen -L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/lib -search_paths_first -headerpad_max_install_names -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMSparcAsmPrinter -lLLVMR600CodeGen -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMR600AsmParser -lLLVMR600Desc -lLLVMR600Info -lLLVMR600AsmPrinter -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMMipsAsmPrinter -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMCppBackendCodeGen -lLLVMCppBackendInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMARMAsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMDebugInfo -lLLVMOption -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lcurses -lpthread -lz -lm -lc++ -lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic /var/folders/9g/8c11l8090p524v5r7873yghc0000gn/T/main-918e82.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-918e82.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040652/stdterminate-undefined-in-cocoa-app), linking with `-lc++` should fix the issue, but in my case it doesn't. I've managed to reduce the issue down to this flag, which is added by `llvm-config --ldflags`:

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2/lib
```

Any idea why this flag is causing the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Try adding `-lc++` at the end.

Comment: to link against the standard library on a mac you need `-lstdc++`

Comment: Already tried that; didnt work. Will try again on the reduced example.

Comment: Didn't work on the reduced example either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I was linking to non-default *stdlibs* using `-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/`. By prepending `-L/usr/lib`, it made sure that OS X's default *stdlib* goes above the homebrewn version.